# sqoop import failing with no command found error

Tags: hbase, sqoop

I am trying to import SQL Server tables directly to HBase, below is the sqoop import syntax

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server_IP:port;databaseName=xxx" --username xxx --password xxx --table sqoop_HBase--hbase-table employeeHBase --column-family amitesh --hbase-row-key empid --hbase-create-table -m 1
```

Here I am facing two issues

1) If I am taking jdbc:sqlserver://server_IP:port;databaseName=xxx in double quotes, I am getting below error

```
5 06:02:05 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_27
17/06/05 06:02:05 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: employeeHBase
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --column-family
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: amitesh
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hbase-row-key
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: empid
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hbase-create-table
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
17/06/05 06:02:05 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
```

2) when I undo the double quotes, and execute the command , I get below error

```
--table or --query is required for import. (Or use sqoop import-all-tables.)
Try --help for usage instructions.
-bash: --username: command not found
```

I pretty sure that I am mistyping command syntax.May be I am wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be space between `--table sqoop_HBase` and `--hbase-table employeeHBase`

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing out the issue. Its working like charm

Comment: @user3521180 Happy to help..:)